# How do I create an HTML tag and place it within an existing HTML tag with content_tag in a helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `@profile` that has_many `positions`. The HTML version looks like this:

```
<h3>Defensive Midfield</h3>
<div class="alternative-positions">
  <small>Attacking Midfield</small><br />
  <small>Right Midfield</small>
</div>
```

However, what I am doing is creating a helper to abstract this view logic, so I am putting a bunch of `content_tags` in my `profile_helper.rb`.

The rules are as follows:

1. when a profile only has 1 position, then it goes into an `h3` tag.
2. when there are 2, the first one goes into `h3`, and the second goes into `small` which is in `div.alternative-positions`.
3. when there are 3, follow #1 & #2 then put the third position within a newly created `<small>` within the EXISTING `div.alternative-positions`.

1 & 2 are straightforward and I can do that with this code:

```
  def player_positions(profile)
    profile.positions.each_with_index do |index, position|
      if index == 0
        content_tag(:h3, position.position_type)
      else
        content_tag(:div, content_tag(:small, position.position_type), class: "alternative-positions")
      end
    end
  end
```

Which was called in my view like so:

```
<%= player_positions(@profile) %>
```

However, the issue I am struggling with is the 3rd one.

I am not quite sure how to select that div, and make sure the newly created `small` tag and content is nested within the existing `div`.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: I kinda doubt that your code works even for two elements. From what I see, it should ignore the first one and emit only the second.

Comment: Correction: I don't see how it would emit any html at all.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev care to add a suggestion then?

Comment: well, you say it works. I'd like to know how. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend treating the first in the list separately (ie not being part of the each clause) eg:

```
def player_positions(profile)
  position_str = ""
  position_str << content_tag(:h3, profile.positions.first.position_type) if profile.positions.size >= 1
  if profile.positions.size >= 2
    # this is the surrounding div for all other positions
    position_str << "<div class='alternative-positions'>"
    profile.positions[1..-1].each_with_index do |index, position|
      position_str << content_tag(:small, position.position_type)
    end
    position_str << "</div>"
  end
  position_str
end
```

or similar (note: not checked for typos or bugs)